# Anylogic - Custom resource choice between two sets

Tags: anylogic

Using AnyLogic service block, I try to seize a resource set using a custom resource choice condition. My criteria for deciding which set to seize is a boolean parameter of the agent. Using the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444416/anylogic-custom-resource-choice-among-resource-sets) I implemented the following code to seize the needed resource:

```java
ResourcePool t_pool = (ResourcePool)pool;
// resource selection condition
if ( (t_pool == resourcePool1) && (agent.bool) ||
     (t_pool == resourcePool2) && (!agent.bool)){
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

This works fine for alternative sets of one resource, however when my sets are composed of more than one resourcePool, the block is unable to seize the set.

For instance with two sets `{commonResourcePool, resourcePool1}` and `{commonResourcePool, resourcePool2}`, I checked the local variable *pool* and it only takes the value of the *commonResourcePool*. Switching the order of the pools did not help.

A solution I found was to use Seize/release blocks to manage the *commonResourcePool*. Would anyone have a more elegant solution, to access both pools using a local variable, chosing the one it selects for instance, or chosing directly one of the resource sets?

(I use AnyLogic PLE 8.4.0)

Expected result: seize the intended set according to the boolean value.
Result obtained: not set is seized and the agent is blocked.
Things I tried:
Switch the order of pools in the set. Resulted in the same outcome: only the *commonResourcePool* is checked by local variable *pool*.

Modifications of the code : I tried to create a new set each time the block is reached, however I was not unable to create the set (ResourceSet does not exist). Code I tried looked like this:

```java
    // create the two resource sets
    ResourceSet resourceSet1 = new ResourceSet();
    ResourceSet resourceSet2 = new ResourceSet();

    // customize the resource choice based on the agent parameter bool
    if (agent.bool.par_cancer) {
        resourceSet1.add(commonResourcePool);
        resourceSet1.add(resourcePool1);
        customizeResourceChoice(resourceSet1);
    } else if (!agent.bool) {
        resourceSet2.add(commonResourcePool);
        resourceSet2.add(resourcePool2);
        customizeResourceChoice(resourceSet2);
    } else {
        // handle invalid agent parameter value
    }
```

Thank you,
Best regards

EDIT:
Here is the [dummy model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPP3o.png) created to reproduce the problem (the same problem appears with the original model).
The function is called in [this section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD2g1.png) of the service block.
The code contained in the function is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwIgy.png).
Sorry for not including these screenshots in the original post.

EDIT 2:
The resource set [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odnW6.png).

Comment: Can you share screenshots of your model and where you're writing your code? It's hard to follow what you're currently doing and what the desired logic is

Comment: I edited the post to add several screenshots showing how this problem occurs. I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you add the resource pools to the 'Resource sets' section of your Service block? You can only choose resources from a specific pool, if the Service (or Seize) block has the pool listed. Also, is your logic "if agent.bool is true, then use commonResourcePool or resourcePool1, else use commonResourcePool or resourcePool2"? Then your code could be much simpler, but I just want to make sure I understand your issue correctly

Comment: Also there's a typo in your `fct_resourceChoice`, I think you meant to write `resourcePool2` in the second row of your `if` condition :)

Comment: Indeed, it's a typo, it's corrected (and it didn't change the problem I'm having).

Comment: Yes, I added the two resource sets in the service block. I would like to seize a resource from each of the pools of the set. For instance, if the boolean represents the nature of a product, I would like to seize a worker with a machine if bool is true, and if it is false, 1 worker and another machine. I add a screenshot of the resource set in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two solutions. The easier would be to have two different service blocks and a SelectOutput before them to choose which block to use, based on the value of `agent.bool`, somewhat like this:
[image]

If you can't use separate Service blocks for some reason, then you need to set the resource sets programmatically. You need to call your function at the 'Resource sets' section of the block (You don't need to use the 'Customize resource choice' section in this case):
[image]

The function `selectResourceSet(boolean getType1)` needs to return with type `ResourcePool[][]`. In this case the function body is the following, where `getType1` is the boolean argument the function takes:

```
ResourcePool[][] choice = {{resourcePool2, commonResourcePool}};
if (getType1) choice[0][0] = resourcePool1;
return choice;
```

This only works if you need to seize 1-1 unit from each set, but I hope this helps you get to the correct solution

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps a lot. As I need to seize 1 unit from each pool, I will implement the second solution you proposed. I did not know how to set the resource sets programmatically, thank you for sharing this solution and for you helpful comments.